# extract text from .doc (not docx)

Tags: python, doc

I checked mose question and answers in stackoverflow and others there is many way to open and read the .docx file not doc by using python

I already checked python-docx library but it only support to docx.

I wanna to open and extract text from .doc file(not docx). Plase help me Because I'm new in python

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tika Python](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python), it's an Apache Tika bindings for python. Another good library is a [textract](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract).

Comment: Non of those are usefull. Textract was for Python2, not for Python3.

Answer (score -1):

I created library to extract text from doc files. It works for C and Python
https://github.com/uvoteam/libdoc
usage example:

```
import extract_doc

with open('./test.doc', 'rb') as myfile:
      data = bytearray(myfile.read())
      print(extract_doc.extract_doc_text(data, len(data)))
```